# If constraint changed (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, valuechangelistener

I'm trying to define an If statement for checking if the value of a constraint has changed.

if the constraint has changed { //do this }

But I'm not sure how to use DidChange for a constraint, or if that even is the correct method.

Currently I'm using the greater than or equal to Int. But That isn't the behavior I'm after. Is there a way to write an if statement for simply checking if the value has changed?

```html
if self.myConstraint.constant >= 50 {
        
            let delay = 0.1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
            let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
            
            dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        
                var iPath = NSIndexPath(forRow:         self.TheTableView.numberOfRowsInSection(1)-1, inSection: self.TheTableView.numberOfSections()-1)
                self.TheTableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(iPath, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Bottom, animated: false)
        
                println("\(countElements(fieldStatus))")
            })
        }
```

Comment: Took me awhile to cobble together an answer, but I provided one below after a lot of editing.  Pretty sure you want to override `traitCollectionDidChange()` and put your code to check `.constant` in that.  If that turns out to be the solution you need, please click the √ next to the answer to accept it and let others (and me) know that the issue is resolved for you. Thanks.

Comment: Hey Thank you, I'm going to try it out but it looks like you've done some good work! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously you're talking about iOS *AutoLayout* constraints (because you're showing the `.constant` property in your example).  `NSLayoutConstraint` is a class and `.constant` a `CGFloat` property in the class declaration.

You need to override the following method from the [UITraitEnvironment](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITraitEnvironment_Ref/index.html) subclasses (of which `UIViewController` is one) to detect constraint set changes, because that's the only way the constraint constants will change. iOS doesn't modify the `.constant` property, but *your* code might, and if you modify `.constant`, then you know you modify it at the time you modify it, so no need to check for `didSet()`.  But iOS *does* swap constraints depending on platform and device orientation, and you can intercept constraint set changes by overriding the `traitCollectionDidChange` method:

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    // Accessing previousTraitCollection causes a crash
}
```

Then you can walk through the current constraints and check the value of `.constant`.

Some people have posted about `willSet()` and `didSet()` property-specific methods, but that only works for properties you define in *your own* class.  `NSLayoutConstraint` is not your own class, and you can't override the behavior of the `.constant` property, because, according to the Swift [documentation on the `extension` keyword](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH24-ID151)

> NOTE Extensions can add new functionality to a type, but they cannot
>   override existing functionality.

You *could* subclass NSLayoutConstraint and override the constant property to intercept value changes as follows, except that doesn't buy you a solution because iOS and Interface Builder will not use or honor your subclass.

```
import UIkit
class MyConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint {
    override var constant : CGFloat {
        get {
            return super.constant
        }
        set {
            // do something extra here
            super.constant = self.constant

       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting answer, I think another way around this could be to define a independent variable integer. (var ValueOfConstraint: int = MyConstraint.constant) and use that integer to see if the value has changed using a RegEx It could make it simpler? What Do you think?

Comment: I thought your goal was to detect changes *at the moment changes were made*, to so your code could immediately respond to an event such as a phone orientation change and the ensuing constraint changes. If you're talking about just comparing a variable's previous value to its previous value, to catch changes after the fact, yes you can copy the value and compare the current value to the saved copy to see if the current value is different, at any point in time.  That's very basic and an extremely common non-platform dependent technique.

Comment: I'm not sure how RegEx buys you anything if you're just trying to figure out if the value of an Int changed. You can compare `if (myIntCurrentValue != myIntPreviousValue)` for that.